# what's 奶酥 in english?

Tags: translation, food

A lot of translations suggest it's "butter biscuit, but that's not the correct thing I'm thinking about.

I'm referring to the filling in bread sold from bakeries that is flaky and sweet, sometimes with raisins in it.

does anyone know what the most accurate translation is?

Answer (score 2):

To my best knowledge it's Chinese [puff (pastry)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puff_pastry) or [Sou](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sou_(pastry)) (transliteration of 酥). These words are not super accurate translation though.

Comment: +1, Puff does sound pretty good in English--it conjures thoughts of puff pastry, which is the point, so it should be understandable. Flaky and sweet, buttery maybe with raisins, sounds a lot like it could be called a pastry, perhaps Chinese pastry/pastries, a lot like the famous Danish pastries.

Answer (score 1):

酥 in Chinese cooking usually refers either to flaky puff pastry or a mixture of flour, oil, and other ingredients. So you're probably talking about the latter. Personally I've used in 葱油饼, a paste made of flour, spring onions, and hot oil.

Something like this is probably what you're talking about:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCTUN2hZgUI
It's a mix of butter, sugar, egg, and flour, so maybe some recipes have milk powder or milk to make a 奶酥 (and raisins)

This is 葱油饼 filling - she refers to the mixture as the 油酥 which makes sense if it's a mixture of oil and flour.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zetjQjqwpdc&t=120

So I don't think there is a direct translation, I might call it a "sweet bun topping/filling" or some other variation of that.